# How to efficiently store repetitive data in Solr without affecting performance

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, search-engine

I am storing data structured a little like this in Solr.

```
[{
    "Product": "Boomerang"
    "Price": 42,
    "Stores": ["Sport Shack", "Joe's Sport Supplies", "Sports and More", "The Outdoor Shop"]
},
{
    "Product": "Juggling Chainsaws"
    "Price": 94,
    "Stores": ["Sport Shack", "Joe's Sport Supplies", "Sports and More","The Outdoor Shop"]
},
{
    "Product": "Chainsaw"
    "Price": 5,
    "Stores": ["Labor Store", "The Outdoor Shop", "Fish n Woodchips"],
}]
```

There are thousands of different products that have the same values for the "Stores" field.

Is there a way to remove the need for repetitively storing these same values without affecting search performance for queries like: 'Find a chainsaw from Labor Store'

This is kind of what I am thinking:

```
[{
    "Product": "Boomerang"
    "Price": 42,
    "StoreGroup": "NoveltySportsStores",
},
{
    "Product": "Juggling Chainsaws"
    "Price": 94,
    "StoreGroup": "NoveltySportsStores",
},
{
    "Product": "Chainsaw"
    "Price": 5,
    "StoreGroup": "OutdoorsStores"
},
{
    "NoveltySportsStores": ["Sport Shack", "Joe's Sport Supplies", "Sports and More", "The Outdoor Shop"]
},
{
    "OutdoorsStores": ["Labor Store", "The Outdoor Shop", "Fish n Woodchips"]
}]
```

Edit:
The example is completely made up. For my real use case, the groups will stay constant and be repeated about 5000 times each, with a total of about 50000 groups.

Comment: When used as `indexed`, the Strings (the store names) will not be stored explicitly for each document. Instead they will be stored once (per segment) and contain a list of IDs (integers) for the documents that they are associated with.
When used as `DocValues`, the Strings will be stored once (per segment) and each document will contain a list of indexes (integers) into that list of Strings.
When uses as `stored` the Strings will be stored explicitly for each document. However, `stored` content is compressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are thinking of Solr/Lucene as a RDBMS, which it is not. Even if it looks to you too much repetition and a loss of resources, it's not. The first way is the natural and best way to index your data.

You could make it work as your second way too, but first is just better, and much simpler.

Comment: .. and the first version will allow faceting and other features to work properly, while the second one will - at some point - require special casing the moment one of the stores isn't included.